# jquery function is not clearing the previous value of a variable inside my function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a function to display a dialog box that asks the users if their checks printed ok, if so, we update a flag in the database for the checks.  I pass this function a "checked_id" which is a value that contains the id of the checks to update.

This code works fine the first time it runs, but when I click on another check to print "checked_id" is the same value as the previously executed id.  Furthermore, the id never gets changed, unless I refresh the browser, which I don't want to have to do every time.

I have verified through firebug that the "checked_id" is actually being changed when calling the function, but something inside the jquery (im guessing) or this function is not clearing out the prevous value in the variable.

How can I fix this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my js function

```
function confirm_print_checks_yes_no(xtitle,msg, btn_yes_txt, btn_no_txt, checked_id, xwidth, xheight)
{
    var button_yes = btn_yes_txt;
    var button_no = btn_no_txt;
    var dialog_buttons = {};

    xwidth = (xwidth) ? xwidth : 300;
    xheight = (xheight) ? xheight : 150;

    dialog_buttons[button_yes] = function (){   update_existing(checked_id,"xml/xml_update_db.php", "print_checks_div", "SQL_UPDATE_multiple_checks", "update_existing", "", "sql_acctg_checks.php"); $(this).dialog("close");
                                                $(this).dialog("close");

    };
    dialog_buttons[button_no] = function(){$(this).dialog("close");};

    $("#modal_confirm_yes_no").html(msg);
    $("#modal_confirm_yes_no").dialog({
                title: xtitle,
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: xheight,
                width: xwidth,
                modal: true,
                buttons: dialog_buttons
            });

    $("#modal_confirm_yes_no").dialog("open");
}
```

usage:

```
onclick="
var checked_ids = getAllCheckedIDs('my_div', 'check_print_chbx');
if(checked_ids)
{
    window.open('print_checks_pdf.php?print_ids=' + checked_ids );
    confirm_print_checks_yes_no(''.mysql_real_escape_string(L_PRINT_CHECKS).', ''.mysql_real_escape_string(L_PRINT_CHECKS_OK_MSG).'', ''.mysql_real_escape_string(L_PRINT_CHECKS_OK_YES_MSG).'', ''.L_NO.'', checked_ids, 500, 200 );
}
else
{
    alert('No Checks Selected')
};"
```

Comment: Could you add the code where you actually call this function? The click event I assume.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code to show the "onclick" events that trigger this.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes along I figured out that "$(this).dialog('destroy');" instead of "$(this).dialog('close'); worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use checked_id variable (with the sam name) also ouside of the function it might cause problems.

You can e.g. make your function return a new value of the "checked_id" and assign it to your variableoutside of the function.

Comment: I tried thanging the variable name outside the function call but got the same results.